# Getting " ValueError: Could not convert string to float: '.' " when input should be accepted as float

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm currently creating a program that sums the input from the user and returns it as a float.

When I try to run the code below with inputs such as "20.1", I receive ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

Shouldn't 20.1 be accepted as a float value?

```
abc = []
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    item = input("Transaction " + str(i) + ": ")
    if item == '':
        break
    abc.extend(item)
abc = [float(k) for k in abc]
print(sum(abc[0:len(abc)]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `abc.extend('20.1')` you get `['2', '0', '.', '1']` and the issue is that you can't convert `.` to float, as the error message suggests. You want to use `abc.append(item)` instead.

This is because extending a list by an iterable object means appending each element of the iterable to the list. A string is iterable over its characters.

---

For what it's worth, you can also do `sum(abc)` straight up, you don't need to do do `sum(abc[0:len(abc)])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really should've played around a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

you should use append instead of extend.

```
abc = []
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    item = input("Transaction " + str(i) + ": ")
    if item == '':
        break
    abc.append(item)
abc = [float(k) for k in abc]
print(sum(abc[0:len(abc)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are specific inputs for specific things. You want to use the float input

```
    float(input())
```

raw_input and input are for strings

```
    int(input)
```

Are for integers